# What is the difference between x1 and x2 which were defined by x1 = tf.Variable(initial_value, 'x2')?

Tags: variables, tensorflow

Can any friend tell me the difference or put some simple codes to show the difference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

x1 is a python variable that is a reference to the tf.Variable you create. 
In the tensorflow graph this tf.Variable will be called x2:0 as you have given it the name x2 when you defined it.